# How can I delay printing till images are loaded?

Tags: c#, printing, process, ms-word

I'm using a `Process` to startup a word document and print it immediately after opening using the the startup `Info.Verb = "Print"`. This works just fine, the document starts printing right away, only the problem is that the document is being printed before the images have been loaded because the images still need to be downloaded from the internet.

Is there a way to delay the printing from the word document?

Comment: If you want some assistance, a code example will be helpful.

Comment: If you want 2 ways interaction with you word document, than you definitely need automation instead of just calling the process. This could be a good start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the upper left round thingy, Word Options, Display, Printing Options, tick the "Update linked data before printing" option.  Ask more questions about this at superuser.com

Comment: Nice solution. The only drawback is that you need to configure in advance all systems before running the application. If the print needs to work on a specific systems, then your solution is fine. Otherwise, you need a method to ensure this update links will work in all cases.

Comment: Thanks, since the application is made to run on a single desktop this solution works just fine. Thank you!